# Is there a way to control the tables alignment in html when using flextable::save_as_html?

Tags: r, flextable

I have generated 2 flextables and want to save them into 1 html file using flextable::save_as_html(). However, I found both are displayed centered in the html output. Is there any way to control the alignment of each table?

my code is:

```
save_as_html(ft1, ft2, path='.../try.html')
```

[image]

This is what I wanted
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible at the moment. A solution could be to create a rmarkdown with html output and set in your chunk `ft.align="left"`, which will align the tables to left. After that you export your file as an html and you have the same. I will show you an example:

````
```{r, ft.align = "left", echo = FALSE}
library(flextable)
ft1 <- flextable( head( iris ) )
ft2 <- flextable( head( mtcars ) )
ft1
ft2
```
````

Output:

[image]

As you can see, it is aligned to the left. To only thing you need to do next is just export the rmarkdown as html.

Comment: Many thanks for your confirmation! Yes, I think it's the only way per the current version of flextable. Hope the series of function save_as_xxxx could be further improved.